# Dispatch to reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Let us say on a click of a button in UI, I want to change 4 pieces of my application state stored in redux.

Is it good to write four action creators and call dispatch four times or write a single actioncreator which creates a single action object and dispatch once? Corresponding reducers will listen to this single action and change state accordingly.

What if one of the action requires fetching data from server?

Please note that order is not a important for me. But atomicity is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trade off in between re-usability and performance.

**4 actions:** Your UI will refresh 4 times but you will be able to reuse the actions independently in the future. Based on how well you have designed your components, refreshing the UI 4 times might not be an issue.

**1 action:** Your UI will only refresh once as you will do one batch update to the redux state. Go with this option if there is no need to call each of the sub actions independently.

**Hybrid:** You can always use a mix of both solutions and create one action that will update the 4 parts at once and separate actions to update individual parts.

In general I go with the 4 actions solution if I am doing very light updates (opening or closing popups/panels for example) and I do one big batch update if I need to do heavy requests somewhere else (during the initial app initialization for example).

Also make sure that in your `mapStateToProps` you are only selecting the information you actually need to avoid unnecessary components updates.

Comment: In trade of between performance and reusability, I think performance should be given more importance.